# iptables for openvpn server not working

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I have these deny statements in my iptables log:

```
RULE 12 -- DENY IN=tun0 OUT=eth1 MAC= SRC=172.16.250.6 DST=192.168.0.11 LEN=84 TOS=0x00 PREC=0
x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=ICMP TYPE=8 CODE=0 ID=20001 SEQ=1
```

Here is my iptables FORWARD table

```
target     prot opt source               destination         
           all  --  172.16.250.0/24      192.168.0.11         /* Allows VPN IPs to connect to computer */
```

not sure why iptables is blocking it.... any ideas?

As always, Thanks all!

Comment: Please post the _entire_ firewall configuration.

Comment: especially the 12th rule :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My iptable rule was missing the -j ACCEPT parameter.

Added

```
`-j ACCEPT`
```

fixed the issue.

-Jim